# Can i scan the wi-fi network traffic using monitor mode?

Tags: python, security, networking, network-programming, scapy

I am making a wi-fi scanner that protects the network from threats, i need to scan all of the packets of all of the devices in the network(with monitor mode) using scapy, problem is that the packets will be encrypted because of WPA2 that gives every device a different key....
is there a way for me to get the keys of the devices so i can scan the traffic?

i tried to search everywhere but i found no solution, the only thing that i can think about is extracting the keys from every 4 way handshake but it will be pretty much impossible.

Comment: Keys change on each connection. You need to capture the initial handshake so you can capture the key exchange between the AP and the client device. There shouldn't be any way to get the key once the connection has been established -- that would make WiFi security meaningless.

Comment: Or are you talking about the WiFi password that you enter into the client device? Even if you have that, it won't allow you to decode the transmissions, it's just used for authentication when the client first connects.

Comment: If it is your network, you could capture at the ethernet interface where the Wi-Fi gets put on to your ethernet, either at the AP or WLC.

Comment: "_is there a way for me to get the keys of the devices_"?  If asking nicely doesn't work, the answer should be __no__ - the whole point of encrypting the traffic is to prevent such eavesdropping.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it, i have the PSK cause it's my network.
so i can listen to every 4 way handshake and use the PSK to create the PTK for every device that will enter the network.